# What does .property(...) does in Emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I have been going through Emberjs docs. I came across topic called `computed property`. I have gone through each and every words there and yet the arguments passed to `.property()` does not make any sense.

Taking the first example from the doc.

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
   }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
  });

  var ironMan = App.Person.create({
  firstName: "Tony",
  lastName:  "Stark"
});

ironMan.get('fullName'); // "Tony Stark"
```

According to the doc

> Notice that the fullName function calls property. This declares the function to be a computed property, and the arguments tell Ember that it depends on the firstName and lastName attributes.

Just to check the significance of `arguments` passed to `.property()` I modified them.

```
fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
   }.property('Captain', 'America')
});
```

`ironMan.get('fullName')` returns  `Tony Stark`.

So the final question is, what is the significance of arguments passed to the `.property()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.property()` is a shorter version of `Ember.computed()`. Elaborating your example

```
fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
   }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

So basically if you don't putup `.property()` it will be a simple method returning full Name after concatenation. But it gets executed all the time whenever you call the method. But if you add `.property()` [basically a computed property], value gets cached and avoid multiple executions.

If there is a change in `firstName` or `lastName`, you might want to update the fullName value in cache. Thats why we pass arguments inside `.property()` as `.property('firstName', 'lastName')` . This is basically concept of observers. So basically in 2nd code you written, you might think its working properly but when there is change in `firstName` or `lastName`, `fullName` won't get changed coz it is observing variables named `Captain`, `America` rather `firstName`, `lastName`.

Comment: well explained, thanx